# KVM Bridge Interface has large number of errors

Tags: linux-networking, kvm-virtualization

I am currently running three KVM hosts which host a range of Linux and Windows virtual machines.

The guests are configured to use br0 as a bridge for networking.

Underlying br0 are two NICs set up such that only one is active at any time but the other kicks in should the primary fail.

I am seeing on all three machines (using nmon) that interfaces kvmbr0 and ens2f0 (the primary NIC in the pair) are showing large numbers of iErrors and oErrors (in the region of 43 million error on a machine with an uptime of less than 24 hours.

I have no idea whether these errors are relevant or how I should proceed to investigate the issue.

If anyone has any idea where to start on this it'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Start from check of the output of these commands:

1. `ip -s -s link show dev <ifacename>` - general statistics counters of network interface
2. `ethtool -S <ifacename>` - low-level counters of NIC
3. `nstat -az` - system metrics of network stack (check the `man nstat` - you can monitor the changing of counters in real-time)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. My issue is not really in seeing that I have errors or how many of them, it's more around how i find out what is causing the errors.